# Cannot see the topics from a different terminal of the same machine when ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1

Tags: ros2

I understand that `ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1` makes topics visible only from the local-host machine.

So I guess that it should be possible to see the topics from another process (terminal) of the same machine.

However, I cannot see the topics from a new terminal. How can I make the topic visible to different terminal session of the same machine?

##### Reprocuction of the issue

###### Terminal 1

```sh
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=99
export ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

###### Terminal 2 (in the same machine with the Terminal 1)

```sh
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=99
export ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1
ros2 topic list  # I cannot see "/chatter"
```

Note that I can see `/chatter` topic in the Terminal2 when `ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0`